# Aspose Word Cloud API - NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, aspose, aspose.words

Does anyone have a working sample in Github or other link that demonstrates the use of Aspose Word Cloud (https://products.aspose.cloud/words) in NodeJS or Python? Case scenario.. you have a MS Word file with content "Hello World". Your demo will upload the .docx file to Aspose Cloud, replace the text content to "How are you, Universe?" and download the .docx file.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aspose-words-cloud contains Cloud SDK for Node.js. Please check  [postReplaceText Unit Test](https://github.com/aspose-words-cloud/aspose-words-cloud-node/blob/6099652fb6220adaf54ead8f6b4cc1c69bf87234/test/documentElements/textTests.ts) that explains how to replace document text using [Aspose.Words API](https://apireference.aspose.cloud/words/#!/TextItems/PostReplaceText).

Hope this helps!